# Merged Resource Dictionary access

Tags: c#, xaml, dll

I have a localization dll with ResourceDisctionary as under

```
<ResourceDictionary
   xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
   xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
   xmlns:cultures="clr-namespace:My_Localization.Cultures"
   xmlns:properties="clr-namespace:My_Localization.Properties">

   <ObjectDataProvider x:Key="Resources" ObjectType="{x:Type cultures:CultureResources}" MethodName="GetResourceInstance"/>

</ResourceDictionary>
```

In another dll I am add this resource dictionary as under

```
<Window.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="/My Localization;component/ResourcesDict.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

        <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BoolToVisibilityConverter"/>
    </ResourceDictionary>

</Window.Resources>
```

In my localization dll I have a property

```
private static ObjectDataProvider m_provider;
public static ObjectDataProvider ResourceProvider
{
    get
      {
       if (m_provider == null)
         // crashes here
           m_provider =(ObjectDataProvider)Application.Current.FindResource("Resources");
       return m_provider;
      }
   }
```

When I try and access this property my application crashes. I get the following exception:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object (Application.current is null)

Can anybody help and why would my dll not find the resource?